# setup.js is deleted in react-boilerplate when running npm run setup

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-boilerplate

I have a very strange problem. I have cloned the react-boilerplate repository from here:

https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate

I add the following dependencies:

```
"body-parser": "^1.15.0",
"cors": "^2.7.1",
"feathers-client": "^1.6.1",
"feathers-rest": "^1.5.0",
"material-ui": "^0.16.0-rc2",
"node-uuid": "^1.4.7",
"react-json-viewer": "^1.1.0",
"request-promise": "^4.1.1",
"rest-client": "^0.1.5",
"socket.io-client": "^1.4.8"
```

When I run 'npm run setup' the file internals/scripts/setup.js is deleted which means that I get an error the next time I run 'npm run setup'.

Any suggestion as to how this can happen will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that

```
npm run setup
```

is only intended to run once. Afterwards I assume I should

```
run npm install
```

I found out after reading this article:

https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/issues/339

Answer (score 0):

In the boiler plate you are working there will be a file setup.js that will be missing in your boilerplate and the path where it should be will be provided in the error, Copy that setup.js file from original boiler plate and paste there where it is missing. This solution worked for me perfectly